# Triggering Enter key in Print Box

Tags: javascript, triggers

I would like to know if there is set of codes that automatically triggers enter key without pressing it.

Take a look in my codes:

Javascript:

```
function printMe()
{
window.print();
window.onfocus=function(){ window.close();}
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printMe()">
```

What I want to happen is, after clicking the button, it will print automatically and does not prompting to Printing Box anymore. The reason why i ask how to trigger enter key automatically is because whenever i go to Print Box, the "Print" button is on focus. Therefore, if i have a code that the enter key triggers automatically, the user will not press the "Print" button anymore, and it will automatically print. Hoping for your help guys. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: There is no way to bypass the print dialogue with javascript, unfortunately.  But, in lieu of that, I'd actually advise against it anyway.  What if the user has the wrong printer selected on default?  They would never be able to print your document.  I installed a pdf printer a while ago and it constantly takes over my default printer.  So, yeah, that could be really frustrating to the end user.

Comment: It's also a security concern. By design, javascript shouldn't be able to get between the user and confirmation prompts from the browser itself (which may be thrown up to confirm actions taken by a nefarious script...).

Comment: vbscript in ie could possibly do it, but that seems to have been deprecated as of IE11 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483782/vbscript-support-in-internet-explorer-11

Comment: @JamesM.Lay Good point, thank you so much!