# How to click on table row element tag?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, row, html-table

I want to click on `<tr>` or `<td>` for select the row. Please find the below HTML code:

```html
<tr class="mcl_data_unsel">
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;">
        &nbsp;<b>HPOrderNo</b> =  <font color="#aa0000"><b>82P980080009</b></font>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have written VBScript code for this, but this is not working:

```vb
WScript.Sleep 10000
For Each a In ie.document.getElementsByTagname("b")
  If a.innerHTML="HPOrderNo" Then
     a.Click
  End If    
Next
```

Comment: what version of IE are you using? take note that there are some IE versions that has limited if not, no longer supports VBscript  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483782/vbscript-support-in-internet-explorer-11#17532816

Comment: i am using Windows7 and IE11

Comment: then that explains why https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn384057%28v=vs.85%29.aspx