# VBScript with HTML frontend

Tags: c#, html, internet-explorer, vbscript

this is my first thread here and I am trying to be as accurate as possible. Furthermore I am not a native speaker so I am sorry in advance for any spelling or grammar mistakes.

I've just started working on a project to automate the parameterization of Siemens drives with the software Siemens Starter v4.4. 
The project description is to write some VB-Scripts to set values in the Starter software and to have an html frontend for the user.

The problem is, that my company is always using the most recent Internet Explorer version. But unfortunetly VBS can only interface correctly with IE10 or lower.

Therefore I am wondering if it is possible to have a standalone IE10 portable installation next to the required scripts. The problem as far as I know is to access the objects used for the communication of IE and VBS.

Of course I am open for any other method of creating a simple frontend.

I am not a professional developer and have to teach myself. Despite of that I have some programming experience in C, C++, C# and VBS. Therefore I would appreciate a solution where I can find some online help and documentation for.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Setting a compatibility flag will allow VBS to run, See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483782/vbscript-support-in-internet-explorer-11

Comment: The above combined with a HTA may be easier  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application

Comment: I just stumbled upon HTA. I'm not that far at the moment, but it is possible to run scripts with parameters from it without copying the whole code into the HTA right ?