# Provider cannot be found when tried to connect to Oracle database (when the script is embedded in HTML file)

Tags: oracle, vbscript, 64-bit

I saved the below code in .vbs file and I am able to connect to Oracle database.

```vb
Set adoConnectionSrc = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strDBDescSrc = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<hostname>)(PORT=<Port number>)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<Service Name>)))"
ConnectstrSrc = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=" & strDBDescSrc & ";User ID=<User ID>;Password=<Password>;"
adoConnectionSrc.Open ConnectstrSrc
```

I inserted the same VBScript code in a HTML file. When I opened the HTML file in IE11, I got the error message

> Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.

```html
<HTML>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"> 
Set adoConnectionSrc = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strDBDescSrc = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<hostname>)(PORT=<Port number>)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<Service Name>)))"
ConnectstrSrc = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=" & strDBDescSrc & ";User ID=<User ID>;Password=<Password>;"
adoConnectionSrc.open ConnectstrSrc
</SCRIPT>
</HTML>
```

My system details:

- Windows 7 (64 bit)
- IE11
- Oracle 11g 64 bit

Comment: Hint: You can't use 64 bit drivers in 32 bit processes.

Comment: VBScript support was dropped in IE11.  See this [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483782/vbscript-support-in-internet-explorer-11) for details.

Comment: @Chris "Provider cannot be found." is not the error you get when your script doesn't run b/c the script language is unsupported.

Comment: @Tomalak: When I open the .vbs file, vbscript runs fine and I am able to connect to Oracle DB. I wanted to input SQL queries in HTML file which I wanted to run at Oracle using VBScript. Hence I tried to embed the same vbscript code in HTML file. But I get the Provider not found error.

Comment: I realize that. Read my comment again. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: I am new to this VBScript. Could you please explain me what is the 32 bit process here.

Comment: Windows not, obviously. Oracle not, either. What remains?

Comment: Use [process explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to confirm. I'm not sure if the standard Windows Task Manager can show whether a process is 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: @Tomalak it can but not by default, if you right click on the columns and choose `Select Columns` you can enable the `Platform` column which tells you if a process is 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: @Krish quick test would be opening up IE 11 using the 64 bit process which should exist here - `%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`. Use that to run your HTML file and the provider issue should be gone.