# Why won't my script work? Error: "Object required: WScript" and does not do anything

Tags: html, vbscript

I am trying to make a VBS file, called dummy.vbs, that automatically types things for a video game I play. It has an HTA file to accompany it, called start.hta, to make it easier for people to use it. However, when I open the HTA file, it displays [this](http://prntscr.com/fl1aqw) error message. And when I click the "Start" button, it does nothing.

What do I fix? Here is the HTA file, then the VBS file.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript" src="dummy.vbs"> </SCRIPT>
<input type='button' value='Start' onclick='startLoop()'>
<input type='button' value='Stop' onclick='stopLoop()'>
<input type='button' value='Set Username To Pay' onclick='inputUsername()'>
<p>Won't work when stopped once; close and reopen. Sorry!</p>
<p> Make sure you set a username to pay, or else the thing won't work! </p>
<img src="think.png" alt="thonk"
style="width:200px;height:200px">
<p style="font-size:300%;","font-family:comicsansms;">Vncz</p>
```

---

```
Set objTimer = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objTyping = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
loopState = true

Do While loopState = true
    
WScript.Sleep "5000"
objTyping.SendKeys "t"
WScript.Sleep "1000"
objTyping.SendKeys "/"
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys "s"
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys "e"
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys "l"
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys "l"
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys " "
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys "a"
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys "l"
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys "l"
WScript.Sleep "1000"
objTyping.SendKeys "~"
WScript.Sleep "1000"

objTyping.SendKeys "t"
WScript.Sleep "1000"
objTyping.SendKeys "/"
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys "p"
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys "a"
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys "y"
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys " "
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys "%usernameToPay%"
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys " "
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys "6"
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys "9"
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys "6"
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys "9"
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys "6"
WScript.Sleep "50"
objTyping.SendKeys "9"
WScript.Sleep "50"

Loop


Sub startLoop()
loopState = true
End Sub

Sub stopLoop()
loopState = false
End Sub

 Sub inputUsername()
usernameToPay = Inputbox("What is the username for your alt to pay? All 
lowercase; '+-' for underscores!","Username to Pay")
End Sub
```

New VBS code, still doesn't work.

```
'''''Defining stuff to make the loop work'''''

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


Sub Wait(Time)
Dim wmiQuery, objWMIService, objPing, objStatus
 wmiQuery = "Select * From Win32_PingStatus Where Address = '1.1.1.1' AND 
Timeout = " & Time
 Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
 Set objPing = objWMIService.ExecQuery(wmiQuery)
 For Each objStatus in objPing
 Next
End Sub

loopState = false
















'Making a loop and telling it to do it only when the Start button is'
'''''pressed'''''


Do While loopState = true
    
Wait(5000)
WshShell.SendKeys "t"
Wait(1000)
WshShell.SendKeys "/"
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys "s"
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys "e"
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys "l"
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys "l"
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys " "
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys "a"
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys "l"
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys "l"
Wait(1000)
WshShell.SendKeys "~"
Wait(1000)

WshShell.SendKeys "t"
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys "/"
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys "p"
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys "a"
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys "y"
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys " "
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys " & usernameToPay & "
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys " "
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys "6"
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys "9"
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys "6"
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys "9"
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys "6"
Wait(50)
WshShell.SendKeys "9"
Wait(50)

Loop













'''''Defining what the buttons in the HTA do'''''


Function startLoop(loopState)
loopState = true
End Function

Function stopLoop(loopState)
 loopState = false
End Function

Sub inputUsername()
usernameToPay = Inputbox("What is the username for your alt to pay? All 
lowercase; '+-' for underscores!","Username to Pay")
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this in a [browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17532816)?

Comment: No, it's an HTML application.

Answer (score 0):

The `wscript` object is only available when running in wscript.exe or cscript.exe.

VBscript has it's own `CreateObject` command and is the normal one you should be using.

Comment: I took the first `wscript.` part out of `WScript.CreateObject(WScript.Shell)`, but now it says the same error message, except now it's saying `WScript.Sleep` is wrong. So would I just take `WScript.` out of `WScript.Sleep`?

Answer (score 0):

A vbs file running from HTA cannot use wscript or cscript. Instead of wscript.sleep, you can use a custom function like:

```
Sub Wait(Time)
  Dim wmiQuery, objWMIService, objPing, objStatus
  wmiQuery = "Select * From Win32_PingStatus Where Address = '1.1.1.1' AND Timeout = " & Time
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
  Set objPing = objWMIService.ExecQuery(wmiQuery)
  For Each objStatus in objPing
  Next
End Sub
```

and then:

```
Wait(5000)
objTyping.SendKeys "t"
Wait(1000)
objTyping.SendKeys "/"
Wait(50)
...
```

You will also need to change  Set objTimer = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

for Set objTimer = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

In other word: remove or replace all wscript or cscript object when working with HTA