# Run hide cmd.exe from website (using javascript or VBScript)

Tags: javascript, vbscript

Why is the following example not working? Additionally, I would like to hide window of **cmd.exe** in `createEmptyFile()` function. The browsers should probably not block this code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Default Page Title</title>

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
      function pingItjs(ipAddress) {
          var oShell = new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell"); 
          oShell.Run("cmd.exe /k ping" + ipAddress); 
      }

      function createEmptyFile() {
          var oShell = new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell"); 
          oShell.Run("cmd.exe /c cd %tmp% && echo hello > EmptyFile"); 
      }
    </script>

<script language="VBScript">
function pingIt(ipAddress)
      set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      WshShell.Run("cmd.exe /k ping " & ipAddress)
end function
</script>


    <a href="javascript:pingItjs('216.58.215.78')">ping</a>


    <div onclick="call pingIt('216.58.215.78')">ping</div>

    <a href="javascript:createEmptyFile()">ping</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browsers are you testing with? `ActiveXObject`s are only supported in IE 11 and Edge

Comment: I tested with firefox, so there is only `VBScript` to solve this problem.

Comment: I meant to say IE 6+ and Edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ActiveX

The [MDN reference states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_JavaScript_extensions/ActiveXObject#Requirements):

> **Note**: Creating an ActiveXObject on a remote server is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 standards mode, Internet Explorer 10 standards mode, Internet Explorer 11 standards mode, and Windows Store apps or later.

So, unless the script is being run in your local machine, the code will not run. It appears that this can be stretched somewhat in the case of intranets, where the [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_JavaScript_extensions/ActiveXObject#Remarks):

> **Important**: ActiveX objects may present security issues. To use the ActiveXObject, you may need to adjust security settings in Internet Explorer for the relevant security zone. For example, for the local intranet zone, you typically need to change a custom setting to "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting."

## VBScript

VBScript is a proprietary Microsoft language and as such only works in IE. See this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17532816/2112866). This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/dn384057(v%3Dvs.85)) (from the Answer just referenced) states that VBScript has been deprecated in IE 11 and will not work in IE 11 in Edge mode.

Possibly, this may help you make VBScript work in IE 11 even in Edge compatibility mode,

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
```

Comment: Updated with VBScript info