# What can I do in order to fix my VBScript error?

Tags: vbscript

So I decided to start learning VBScript coding language, but I had some issues with running it. Here is what I have done:

1. I made a code, specifically this code:
   [Picture of the source code in/of HTML and VBScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRwt6.png)
2. I installed IE (internet explorer) since I saw that VBScript is only supported by IE.
3. The code I did wrote, I wrote it on notepad, saved the file, and gave the file extension: .vbs (file name was "test").
4. I right-clicked test.vbs, clicked Properties, changed "Open With" to Microsoft (R) Windows Based Script Host.
5. I ran the file.
6. This Error occurred: [Picture of the Error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72YIY.png)

So may I ask, what wrong did I do? or what is wrong? like did I personally do a mistake, or is it something like if Windows 10 does not support VBScript, or if VBScript is not supported anymore? I as well saw a thread of Microsoft saying that VBScript support will be stopped for Windows 7, 8; though I dont know the exact mistake I have done.

Thanks for the answers.

P.S. I as well tried the file in the extension .htm, but It did not work though I ran it on both firefox and IE.

Comment: 1. Don't post links/images of code or errors. Add the code as text. 2. The errors are not in English - if you posted them as text, we could at least run it through google translate. 3. I am pretty certain you need to run the web page through a server like [IIS](https://www.iis.net/).

Comment: Why did you choose VBScript? It’s a dead language. I suggest you learn something that is currently in use.

Comment: How is this question still being asked? It’s been covered so many times already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBScript support in Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483782/vbscript-support-in-internet-explorer-11)

Answer (score 0):

VBScript in HTML is only supported by the Trident (MSHTML) browser engine used by Internet Explorer 10 and below and Microsoft HTML Applications (MSHTAs or HTAs). Your script failed to run as .VBS because it's not a VBScript file. It failed to run in IE because IE 11 and above only supports JavaScript.

In order to run your script, change the extension to **.HTA**. It will then work in Windows 7, 8, 10 and 11, and additionally allow for full access to the local computer's resources (files, registry keys, etc.).

If you really want to create a web page (to run from the Internet), use JavaScript instead of VBScript and save it as .HTM.

Comment: Kind of right but technically you can still run VBScript in IE 11 by [using the IE compatibility meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17532816/692942) to use IE10 document mode.

Comment: This has been covered over 13 years ago in the duplicate target.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you misunderstood the "runs only in IE" part of VBScript. Yes, IE is the only browser that runs inline-VBScript in HTML files. But no, you don't need IE *(or HTML, for that matter)* to execute a simple VBScript (*.vbs) file.

You received that error, because the Windows Scripting Host doesn't "understand" HTML. Hence, it complains at line 1, column 1 about something it can't identify as VBScript.

Here's [Microsoft's VBScript Primer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee198896(v=technet.10)).

For you classic *Hello World!* VBScript, simply paste this one line into a file...

```
MsgBox "...from the Scripting host with love!",, "Hello World..."
```

... and make sure *(as you already did)* that the file's extension is *.vbs. Then simply double-click to execute it.

Comment: This has been covered over 13 years ago in the duplicate target.